# Ubuntu 20.04 not getting installed on Dell 3020 optiplex

Tags: 20.04

I am trying to install Ubuntu 20.04 on my Dell Optiplex 3020M.

It is not installing.

All I get is the purple screen.

I have tried also with 18.04 it installs properly.

So kindly suggest any solution

Comment: Does your computer meet the minimum specs for 20.04?

Comment: yeah My computer have 4GB RAM and processor  Intel(R) Pentium(R) CPU G3250T @ 2.80GHz  and 500 GB hard disk

Comment: Have you tried to upgrade from 18.04 to 20.04 with `sudo do-release-upgrade` ?

Comment: i have  not did upgrade i try fresh installation where the system was already installed windows 10 .and its able to install centos 7 also but only Ubuntu 20.04 only not getting installed .i have tried with two more systems which all are of same model and facing same issue

Comment: kindly sombody suggest any resolution for this I have tried with both Legacy and UEFI modes .

Comment: Sometime the splash screen is not properly configured. Try to switch console by pressing ALT-F2, ALT-F1. You should then see logon screen.